# Laravel Scribe API docs generation - Public properties `auth`, `controller`, `method`, `route` not found on Knuckles\Camel\Output\OutputEndpointData

Tags: laravel, scribe, api-doc

I use knuckleswtf/scribe package in my laravel apps to auto generate api docs from routes.
in one of laravel apps when I execute `php artisan scribe:generate` i get following error:

```
Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObjectError 

  Public properties `auth`, `controller`, `method`, `route` not found on Knuckles\Camel\Output\OutputEndpointData

  at vendor/spatie/data-transfer-object/src/DataTransferObjectError.php:15
     11▕     public static function unknownProperties(array $properties, string $className): DataTransferObjectError
     12▕     {
     13▕         $propertyNames = implode('`, `', $properties);
     14▕ 
  ➜  15▕         return new self("Public properties `{$propertyNames}` not found on {$className}");
     16▕     }
     17▕ 
     18▕     public static function invalidTypes(array $invalidTypes): DataTransferObjectError
     19▕     {

  1   vendor/spatie/data-transfer-object/src/DataTransferObject.php:89
      Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObjectError::unknownProperties()

  2   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/camel/Output/OutputEndpointData.php:103
      Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject::__construct()

  3   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/camel/BaseDTO.php:29
      Knuckles\Camel\Output\OutputEndpointData::__construct()

  4   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:182
      Knuckles\Camel\BaseDTO::create()

  5   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:126
      Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::mergeAnyEndpointDataUpdates()

  6   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:71
      Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::extractEndpointsInfoFromLaravelApp()

  7   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/GroupedEndpoints/GroupedEndpointsFromApp.php:49
      Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::extractEndpointsInfoAndWriteToDisk()

  8   vendor/knuckleswtf/scribe/src/Commands/GenerateDocumentation.php:51
      Knuckles\Scribe\GroupedEndpoints\GroupedEndpointsFromApp::get()

  9   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36
      Knuckles\Scribe\Commands\GenerateDocumentation::handle()

  10  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:40
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()

  11  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:93
      Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()

  12  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:37
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()

  13  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:653
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()

  14  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
      Illuminate\Container\Container::call()

  15  vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:298
      Illuminate\Console\Command::execute()

  16  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:121
      Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run()

  17  vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1024
      Illuminate\Console\Command::run()

  18  vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:299
      Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand()

  19  vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
      Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun()

  20  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:94
      Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run()

  21  vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:129
      Illuminate\Console\Application::run()

  22  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I tried to use different route file or controller. even commented out all routes and just left one anonymous route.
the only way it works, is that no routes are in my app. which gives these logs:

```
ⓘ Extracting intro and auth Markdown files to: .scribe
✔ Extracted intro and auth Markdown files to: .scribe
ⓘ Writing Blade docs...
✔ Wrote Blade docs to: resources/views/scribe/
✔ Wrote Laravel assets to: public/vendor/scribe/
ⓘ Generating Postman collection
✔ Wrote Postman collection to: storage/app/scribe/collection.json
ⓘ Generating OpenAPI specification
✔ Wrote OpenAPI specification to: storage/app/scribe/openapi.yaml
Checking for any pending upgrades to your config file...

✔ All done. Visit your docs at http://diet.local/docs
```

any help would be appreciated.